# solution verification on GREE number theory problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, modular-arithmetic

find the remainder of

$$3^{20}$$

divided by 7. So we know what number its congruent mod 7 too.

I know

$$3^3 \equiv (-1) \mod 7$$

Thus

$$3^{18} \equiv 1 \mod 7$$

multiplying through by $3^2$ we get

$$3^{20} \equiv 3^2 \mod 7 \equiv 2 \mod 7$$

So the answer is $2$?

Comment: You're correct. One quite minor, slightly easier, thing is you could have used that $3^6 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$, which comes from [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

Comment: This is a special case of the method described in the linked dupes. Please note that for solution-verification questions to be on-topic you should state precisely what step you doubt, and why you doubt it.